# Complex root won't work

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So I'm trying to get this:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%288*sqrt%283%29%29%2F%28z%5E4%2B8%29%3Di](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%288%2asqrt%283%29%29/%28z%5E4%2b8%29=i)

And I've calculated $z^4=16 \left( \cos (\frac{- \pi}{3})+ \sin ( \frac{- \pi}{3}) \right)$

So I'm trying to find the roots using the formula:

$ r^{1/n} = \left( \cos ( \frac { \theta + 2 \pi \cdot k}{n}) + i \cdot \sin ( \frac{ \theta + 2 \pi \cdot k}{n}) \right) $

But my result does not equal. Take a look:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16%5E%281%2F4%29*%28cos%28%28%28-pi%2F12%29%29%2F4%29%2Bi*sin%28%28%28-pi%2F12%29%29%2F4%29%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16%5E%281/4%29%2a%28cos%28%28%28-pi/12%29%29/4%29%2bi%2asin%28%28%28-pi/12%29%29/4%29%29)

This is for $k=0$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your sine and cosine at the WA link have a $48$ in the denominator.  They should only have a $12$ there.  It looks like you may have divided by $4$ *twice*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, your error is in determining the argument of $z^4$.

I would start off by writing the reciprocal of both sides giving:
$$\frac{z^4+8}{8\sqrt{3}}=-i$$

Solving above equation for $z$ gives:

$$z^4=-8-8\sqrt{3}i$$

Thus, modulus of $z^4$ is $16$, as you correctly wrote. Your error is in determining the argument, you have to consider where $z^4$ lies in the complex plane. Since both the real and imaginary components are negative, it is in 3rd quadrant.

[image]

So, to find the arg, we take:

$$\pi+arctan(\frac{-8\sqrt{3}}{-8})=\frac{4\pi}{3}$$

Thus $z^4=16cis(\frac{4\pi}{3})$. Work from that and you should get the correct answer.

Comment: How come we say arctan of -8/i ? I'd think that we'd have pi + the corner that is formed if you draw a segment from the red dot onto the real line, and that corner is Tan(im/re). The imaginary line is the opposite and the real one is the adjacent ?

Comment: You are correct, I made a minor error. Fixed it. Do you understand the rest?

Comment: Yes! It works now! Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing. I'm looking over the next assignment and now I'm supposed to show for some $Rw= \frac{w+w}{2} $ and I don't even know what these are...Never seen them in the book. The R is some really weird font and one of the w's is the conjugate (with a line over it). Do you know what this thing is called or what I can search for?

Comment: $\Re$? That just simply means the real part of a complex number. So, anything that is not multiplied by $i$. Try it out, if you have any trouble, make another question and I'll be glad to help.